# RegEx for adding a space in a special pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

*Quick note:* I know markdown parsers don't care about this issue. It's for the sake of visual consistency in the md file and also experimentation.

**Sample**:

```
# this
##that
###or this other
```

**Goal**: read each line and,if a markdown header does not have a space after the pound/hashtag sign, add one so that it would look like:

```
# this
## that
### or this other
```

My non-regex attempt:

```php
function inelegantFunction (string $string){
    $array = explode('#',$string);
    $num = count($array);
    $text = end($array);
    return str_repeat('#', $num-1)." ".$text;
}

echo inelegantFunction("###or this other"); 
// returns  ### or this other
```

This works, but it has no mechanism to match the unlikely case of seven '#'.

Regardless of efficacy, I would like to figure out how to do this with regex in php (and perhaps javascript if that matters).

Comment: So you are basically checking for `^#+\S` and want to add a space there?

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('~^#+(?![ #])~m', '$0 ', $s)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FV87UO/2)) will do. In JS, `s.replace(/^#+(?![ #])/mg, '$& ')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FV87UO/1)).

Comment: I *suspect*  so. What I had tried was '/#(?<hash>[^\s#]+)/' but, with regex, I am always navigating in the dark and hoping to get better at it.

Comment: If `#` is always followed by a *word character* in your input: Search for [`^#+\K\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4dRoRZ/1/) and replace with space. Replace `+` with eg [`{1,6}`](https://regex101.com/r/4dRoRZ/2) for limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to match `(?m)^#++\K\S` which matches lines starting with one or more number signs then replace it with  `$0` in your function:

```
return preg_replace('~(?m)^#++\K\S~', ' $0', $string);
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/UgZhY)

To limit the number of `#`s to six use:

```
(?m)^(?!#{7})#++\K\S
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I did not know the \K reset option. Although it's not at all likely in markdown files, is there anything to ensure that, say, 10 # are ignored? Essentially checking only up to 6 #

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that a simple expression with a right char-list boundary might be working here, maybe:

```
(#)([a-z])
```

If we might be having more chars, we can simply add it to `[a-z]`.

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8IxGS/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(#)([a-z])/m';
$str = '#this
##that
###that
### or this other';
$subst = '$1 $2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very elegant answer. Much appreciated.